# Remove blank space from the right side of the webpage with Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[image]

So it seems it's a typical problem, but I haven't been able to remove that bloody blank space that completely disfigures my webpage on mobile view.

I have tried to remove individually each element to see what's happening, but I can't see it.

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1">
    <!--Boostrap jQuery-->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!--Boostrap-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7"
        crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!--Favicon-->
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="media/favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32" />
    <!--Mi CSS-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilo.css">

    <title> TRAMA & DRAMA | Vestuario y producción</title>
</head>

<body>


    <!-- navbar -->
    <nav id="navegacion" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top navbar-wrapper">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false"
                    aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Navegación</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
            </div>
            <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="#">¿Quiénes somos?</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">¿Qué hacemos?</a></li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"><img id="logo" src="media/logo-menu.png" alt=""></a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Nuestros proyectos</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contacto</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <!--fin del navbar-->

    <!--Barra rosa única del navbar-->
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 barraRosa-nav"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--Sldeshow -->
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row ">
            <div id="pasion-div">
                <div class="text-center">
                    <h1 id="pasion-texto">Pasión por el vestuario</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--Barra rosa-->
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 barraRosa"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 text-center img-responsive" id="id-quienes">
                <img id="img-vestido" src="media/vestido.png" alt="Vestido">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--Barra rosa-->
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 barraRosa"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 text-center fuente-sans" id="hacemos">
                <h1>¿Qué hacemos?</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="row text-center fuente-merri">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <img src="media/icono-renta.png" alt="">
                <p class="hacemos-headers"><b>Renta de vestuario</b></p>
                <!--<p class="hacemos-descripciones fuente-merri">Nosotros hacemos muchas cosas bien chodas</p>-->
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <img src="media/icono-coordinacion.png" alt="">
                <p class="hacemos-headers"><b>Coordinación de vestuario</b></p>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <img src="media/icono-diseno.png" alt="">
                <p class="hacemos-headers"><b>Diseño de vestuario</b></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row text-center fuente-merri">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <img src="media/icono-espacios.png" alt="">
                <p class="hacemos-headers"><b>Renta de espacios para cursos</b></p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <img src="media/icono-realizacion.png" alt="">
                <p class="hacemos-headers"><b>Realización</b></p>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <img src="media/icono-mantenimiento.png" alt="">
                <p class="hacemos-headers"><b>Mantenimiento de vestuario</b></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--Barra rosa-->
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 barraRosa"></div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div id="proyectos">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12 text-center fuente-sans">
                    <h1>Nuestros proyectos</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12 text-center fuente-merri">
                    <p>Nos interesa que conozcas más a fondo los proyectos que llevamos a cabo en <b>Trama & Drama</b>.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="row text-center fuente-sans">
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <img src="media/circ-1.png" alt="">
                    <h4>Diseño de vestuario</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <img src="media/circ-2.png" alt="">
                    <h4>Producción y coordinación de vestuario</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <img src="media/circ-3.png" alt="">
                    <h4>Renta de vestuario</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <div class="row text-center fuente-sans">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <img src="media/circ-4.png" alt="">
                    <h4>Servicio social</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <img src="media/circ-5.png" alt="">
                    <h4>Actividades del mes</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <!--Barra rosa-->
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 barraRosa"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 text-center fuente-sans">
                <h1>Contacto</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 text-center fuente-merri">
                <div id="contacto-desc">
                    <p>¡Nos encantan los nuevos retos! Escríbemos, llámanos o platícanos de tu proyecto.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row text-center">
            <form role="form">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" name="" value="" placeholder="Tu nombre o el nombre de la empresa">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="email" name="" value="" placeholder="Correo electrónico">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input id="textfield" type="text" name="" value="" placeholder="Tu mensaje">
                </div>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">ENVIAR</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="row text-center fuente-merri">
            <p class="ch">Teléfonos</p>
            <p class="cs">044 55 5601 1231</p>
            <br>
            <p class="ch">Correo eletrónico</p>
            <p class="cs">info@tramaydrama.mx</p>
            <br>
            <p class="ch">Dirección</p>
            <p class="cs">Eligio Villamar, No. 20, San Diego Churubusco. C.P: 04120, Delegación Coyoacan</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <!--Barra rosa-->
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 barraRosa-negra"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--Footer-->
    <footer>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row fuente-sans">
                <div class="col-sm-12 text-center" id="futer">
                    <a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/tramaydrama/?fref=ts"><img src="media/icono-fb.png" alt="Facebook"></a>
                    <img src="media/icono-inst.png" alt="Instagram">
                    <img src="media/icono-vimeo.png" alt="vimeo">
                    <p id="copyrights">Copyright Trama & Drama 2016 &copy;. Todos los derechos reservados | Página web por <a target="_blank"
                            href="http://animanoir.com"><b>Animanoir/Claque</b></a> | Diseño por <b>Cúmulo</b>.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>

    <!--Bootstrap jQuery-->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8="
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

CSS code:

```
/*Fuentes*/
@import 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora:700i'; /*Header*/
@import 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather'; /*Títulos*/
@import 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300'; /*Subtítulos*/


body{
    padding-top: 70px;
    overflow: hidden 
}

footer{
    background-color: #B7254E;
    color: white;
}

/*Los botones dentro de una font: ;ma*/
form > button{
    width: 50%;
    background-color: #5A1741 !important;
    text-align: left !important;
}

/*ids*/


#copyrights{
    padding-top: 25px;
}

#futer{
    padding-top: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
}

#textfield{
    height: 150px;
}

#proyectos{
    background-color: #5A1741;
    color: white;
}

#id-quienes{
    color: white;
    background-color: #5A1741;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

#imagen-fondo{
    position: relative;;
    z-index: -1;
}

#logo{
    width: 13em;
}

#contacto-desc{
    color: #692C52;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#pasion-div{
    background-image: url("media/portada-mejor.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;

    min-height: 650px;
    padding: 13px;

    font-size: 1.2em;

    /*Para que se centre el texto*/
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

#pasion-div > div{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}

#pasion-texto{
    font-family: 'Lora', serif;
    color: white;
    font-size: 5em;
    /*width: 400px;*/
}

#quienes{
    background-color: #5A1741;
    height: 200px;
}

/*clases*/

.ch{
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #5A1741;
}

.cs{
    color: #5A1741;
    color: #B7254E;
}

.navbar-nav{
    background-color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.navbar-nav {
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    margin: 0;
    color: #B7254E;
}
.navbar-nav > li {
    float:none;
    display:table-cell;
    text-align:center;

}

.navbar a{
    color: #B7254E !important;
}

.barraRosa-nav{
    width: 100%;
    height: 45px;
    background-color: #B7254E;
}

.barraRosa{
    width: 100%;
    height: 5px;
    background-color: #B7254E;
}

.barraRosa-negra{
    width: 100%;
    height: 5px;
    background-color: #5A1741
}

.hacemos-descripciones{
    color: #B7254E;
}

.hacemos-headers{
    color: #5A1741;
}

.fuente-merri{
    font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
}

.fuente-sans{
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}

/*Posicionar verticalmente en el centro*/   
.vertical-align {
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block;
}

.form-group > input{
    width: 50%;
}
```

Comment: it could be the html that is causing it, for eg, a very long url can cause that, and have nothing to do with your css.

Comment: Validate your html: https://www.onlinewebcheck.com/check.php | also, your CSS is missing a ; after "hidden"

Comment: @Johannes I pasted the HTML.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as an answer, but include an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are generally of higher quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add

```
html, body { margin: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you used to much `class="row"` even if there is no child columns. 
for example you did this

```
<!--Sldeshow -->
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row "> /*remove this class="row" because you're not using col*/
        <div id="pasion-div">
            <div class="text-center">
                <h1 id="pasion-texto">Pasión por el vestuario</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and it should be like this

```
    <!--Sldeshow -->
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div> /*yep, this is right*/
        <div id="pasion-div">
            <div class="text-center">
                <h1 id="pasion-texto">Pasión por el vestuario</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

so why removing the class row?
if you look at bootstrap.css you can see the `.row` have `margin: 0 -15px`, so why is that?
so that it can remove the excess `15px` of the `col-xx-00` class.
So try removing the `class='row'` that occupies the unnecessary white spaces.

here, i tried to remove the unnecessary rows.

```html
    <!-- navbar -->
    <nav id="navegacion" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top navbar-wrapper">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false"
                    aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Navegación</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
            </div>
            <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="#">¿Quiénes somos?</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">¿Qué hacemos?</a></li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#"><img id="logo" src="media/logo-menu.png" alt=""></a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Nuestros proyectos</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contacto</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <!--fin del navbar-->

    <!--Barra rosa única del navbar-->
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 barraRosa-nav"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--Sldeshow -->
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div> /*removed class="row" here*/
            <div id="pasion-div">
                <div class="text-center">
                    <h1 id="pasion-texto">Pasión por el vestuario</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--Barra rosa-->
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 barraRosa"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 text-center img-responsive" id="id-quienes">
                <img id="img-vestido" src="media/vestido.png" alt="Vestido">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--Barra rosa-->
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 barraRosa"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 text-center fuente-sans" id="hacemos">
                <h1>¿Qué hacemos?</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="row text-center fuente-merri">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <img src="media/icono-renta.png" alt="">
                <p class="hacemos-headers"><b>Renta de vestuario</b></p>
                <!--<p class="hacemos-descripciones fuente-merri">Nosotros hacemos muchas cosas bien chodas</p>-->
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <img src="media/icono-coordinacion.png" alt="">
                <p class="hacemos-headers"><b>Coordinación de vestuario</b></p>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
                <img src="media/icono-diseno.png" alt="">
                <p class="hacemos-headers"><b>Diseño de vestuario</b></p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row text-center fuente-merri">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <img src="media/icono-espacios.png" alt="">
                <p class="hacemos-headers"><b>Renta de espacios para cursos</b></p>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <img src="media/icono-realizacion.png" alt="">
                <p class="hacemos-headers"><b>Realización</b></p>
            </div>
            <div> /*removed class="row" here*/
                <img src="media/icono-mantenimiento.png" alt="">
                <p class="hacemos-headers"><b>Mantenimiento de vestuario</b></p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--Barra rosa-->
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 barraRosa"></div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <div id="proyectos">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12 text-center fuente-sans">
                    <h1>Nuestros proyectos</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-12 text-center fuente-merri">
                    <p>Nos interesa que conozcas más a fondo los proyectos que llevamos a cabo en <b>Trama & Drama</b>.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br>
            <div class="row text-center fuente-sans">
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <img src="media/circ-1.png" alt="">
                    <h4>Diseño de vestuario</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <img src="media/circ-2.png" alt="">
                    <h4>Producción y coordinación de vestuario</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <img src="media/circ-3.png" alt="">
                    <h4>Renta de vestuario</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <div class="row text-center fuente-sans">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <img src="media/circ-4.png" alt="">
                    <h4>Servicio social</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                    <img src="media/circ-5.png" alt="">
                    <h4>Actividades del mes</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    <!--Barra rosa-->
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 barraRosa"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 text-center fuente-sans">
                <h1>Contacto</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 text-center fuente-merri">
                <div id="contacto-desc">
                    <p>¡Nos encantan los nuevos retos! Escríbemos, llámanos o platícanos de tu proyecto.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="text-center">  /*removed class="row" here*/
            <form role="form">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="text" name="" value="" placeholder="Tu nombre o el nombre de la empresa">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="email" name="" value="" placeholder="Correo electrónico">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <input id="textfield" type="text" name="" value="" placeholder="Tu mensaje">
                </div>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">ENVIAR</button>
            </form>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="row text-center fuente-merri">
            <p class="ch">Teléfonos</p>
            <p class="cs">044 55 5601 1231</p>
            <br>
            <p class="ch">Correo eletrónico</p>
            <p class="cs">info@tramaydrama.mx</p>
            <br>
            <p class="ch">Dirección</p>
            <p class="cs">Eligio Villamar, No. 20, San Diego Churubusco. C.P: 04120, Delegación Coyoacan</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <!--Barra rosa-->
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 barraRosa-negra"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!--Footer-->
    <footer>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row fuente-sans">
                <div class="col-sm-12 text-center" id="futer">
                    <a target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/tramaydrama/?fref=ts"><img src="media/icono-fb.png" alt="Facebook"></a>
                    <img src="media/icono-inst.png" alt="Instagram">
                    <img src="media/icono-vimeo.png" alt="vimeo">
                    <p id="copyrights">Copyright Trama & Drama 2016 &copy;. Todos los derechos reservados | Página web por <a target="_blank"
                            href="http://animanoir.com"><b>Animanoir/Claque</b></a> | Diseño por <b>Cúmulo</b>.</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
```

or if you want, instead of removing `row`s, add `col-sm-12` to the following tag. For example `<div class="row"><div class="col-sm-12"><p>hey~</p></div></div>`

Comment: I used your code but still, the vertical white space is there.